# How to use react native on codeanywhere.com

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs, codeanywhere

I was wondering how to create a project in codeanywhere.com which supports react native. It isn't included in the initial containers so you somehow have to add it later but I am confused with which container it would be better to select.

I was also wondering if it includes intelligence for JSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js Development Stack with Node.js, nvm, npm, Redis and MySQL Server preinstalled.